# Use Pandas.groupby to select a row in a group with some criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3 , 3, 4], 
                     'type': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 
                     'hist' : [1,2,1,3,0,3,4]})

data
Out[1]: 
   hist  name type
0     1     1    A
1     2     2    B
2     1     2    B
3     3     2    C
4     0     3    B
5     3     3    C
6     4     4    A
```

I would expect this data becomes like

```
data 
Out[2]: 
   hist  name type
0     1     1    A
1     2     2    B
2     3     2    C
3     0     3    B
4     3     3    C
5     4     4    A
```

It means that I firstly apply `groupby(['name', 'type'])`, then for each group, I want to select column which have highest value in columns hist. For example, I get idea from

```
gps = data.groupby(['name', 'type'])
keys  = gps.groups.viewkeys()
Out[3]: dict_keys([(3L, 'C'), (3L, 'B'), (2L, 'B'), (2L, 'C'), (1L, 'A'), (4L, 'A')])
gps.get_group(list(keys)[2])
Out[4]: 
   hist  name type
1     2     2    B
2     1     2    B
```

My approach is

```
def mfunc(df):
    if len(df) > 1:
        idx = df['hist'].idxmax()
        l_idx = df.index.tolist()
        rm_list = list(set(l_idx) - set([idx]))
        df.drop(pd.Int64Index(rm_list), inplace=True)
    else: 
        pass
result = data.groupby(['name', 'type']).apply(mfunc)
```

But `result` is an empty DataFrame.

Could you help me to use apply function in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pivot_table` for that purpose:

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(data, index=['name', 'type'], aggfunc=max).reset_index()
In [20]: df1
Out[20]:
   name type  hist
0     1    A     1
1     2    B     2
2     2    C     3
3     3    B     0
4     3    C     3
5     4    A     4
```

If you need that particular order of your columns you could reorder the result:

```
In [33]: df2 = df1[['hist', 'name', 'type']]

In [34]: df2
Out[34]:
   hist  name type
0     1     1    A
1     2     2    B
2     3     2    C
3     0     3    B
4     3     3    C
5     4     4    A
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more efficient approach:

```
data.groupby(['name', 'type'])['hist'].max()
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
data.sort('hist', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'type'])
```